# I'd like [for?] there to be

Tags: phrase-usage

Do you say "I'd like there to be something" or "I'd like for there to be something"? Or does it vary with dialect or style, and if so, how?

Comment: Could you please enter a whole sentence, like where you encountered this line or did you make it up on your own?

Comment: I'm with @DhanishthaGhosh, it would certainly help to give a particular example - but I think "I'd like for" is more common in US English than UK English